# Adding timedelta to local datetime, unexpected behaviour accross DST shift

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timedelta, dst

I just stumbled accross this surprising behaviour with Python datetimes while creating datetimes accross DST shift.

Adding a timedelta to a local datetime might not add the amount of time we expect.

```
import datetime as dt
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

# Midnight
d0 = dt.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Europe/Paris"))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Paris'))
d0.isoformat()
# '2020-03-29T00:00:00+01:00'

# Before DST shift
d1 = d0 + dt.timedelta(hours=2)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 2, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Paris'))
d1.isoformat()
# '2020-03-29T02:00:00+01:00'

# After DST shift
d2 = d0 + dt.timedelta(hours=3)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 3, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Paris'))
d2.isoformat()
# '2020-03-29T03:00:00+02:00'

# Convert to UCT
d1u = d1.astimezone(dt.timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 1, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
d2u = d2.astimezone(dt.timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 1, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

# Compute timedeltas
d2 - d1
# datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
d2u - d1u
# datetime.timedelta(0)
```

I agree d1 and d2 are the same, but shouldn't d2 be '2020-03-29T04:00:00+02:00', then?

```
d3 = d0 + dt.timedelta(hours=4)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 4, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Paris'))
```

Apparently, when adding a timedelta (ex. 3 hours) to a local datetime, it is added regardless of the timezone and the delta between the two datetimes (in real time / UTC) is not guaranteed to be that timedelta (i.e. it may be 2 hours due to DST). This is a bit of a pitfall.

What is the rationale? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: There are plenty of problems related to time calculations, not just DST, and it's really annoying as it leads to many unnecessary code. I'd suggest you to avoid timezones at all, simply cast any input datetime to UTC, make all calculations in UTC only and set timezone back only for output *(if needed)*.

Comment: @OlvinRoght instead of just *avoiding* time zones, why not work out a proper way to deal with them? Yes, there are caveats, but UTC is no silver bullet either, and in the end the world runs on time zones, not UTC (although I'd prefer the latter as well ^^)

Comment: @FObersteiner, *"proper way to deal with them"* turns into a mess if there're descent amount of dates from different zones that's why UTC actually exists, I suppose. But yes, that's not a rule to use just UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationale is : timedelta arithmetic is wall time arithmetic. That is, it includes the DST transition hours (or excludes, depending on the change). See also [P. Ganssle's blog post](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/02/aware-datetime-arithmetic.html) on the topic .

An illustration:

```py
import datetime as dt
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

# Midnight
d0 = dt.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Europe/Paris"))

for h in range(1, 4):
    print(h)
    print(d0 + dt.timedelta(hours=h))
    print((d0 + dt.timedelta(hours=h)).astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC")), end="\n\n")
```

```
1
2020-03-29 01:00:00+01:00
2020-03-29 00:00:00+00:00 # as expected, 1 hour added

2
2020-03-29 02:00:00+01:00 # that's a non-existing datetime...
2020-03-29 01:00:00+00:00 # looks normal

3
2020-03-29 03:00:00+02:00
2020-03-29 01:00:00+00:00 # oops, 3 hours timedelta is only 2 hours actually!
```

---

Need more confusion? Use naive datetime. Given that the tz of my machine (Europe/Berlin) has the same DST transitions as the tz used above:

```py
d0 = dt.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 0, 0)

for h in range(1, 4):
    print(h)
    print(d0 + dt.timedelta(hours=h))
    print((d0 + dt.timedelta(hours=h)).astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC")), end="\n\n")
```

```
1
2020-03-29 01:00:00       # 1 hour as expected
2020-03-29 00:00:00+00:00 # we're on UTC+1

2
2020-03-29 02:00:00       # ok 2 hours...
2020-03-29 00:00:00+00:00 # wait, what?!

3
2020-03-29 03:00:00
2020-03-29 01:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: Thanks. You code sample is more or less the same as mine except it is much clearer the way you write it. The link you provide gives a comprehensive explanation. Still, what a pitfall. It is kind of inconsistent that the same operation (t1 + t2.astimezone(tz)) behaves differently for a single value of tz. But as said in the article, there is no ideal solution.

Comment: @Jérôme I've been there myself, very confusing. I'd say that's one of the three major pitfalls in Python's datetime/timezone implementation. Along with "naive datetime = local time" and pytz's "localize trap", although the latter is not strictly Python standard library (although it goes back to features missing there in older versions).