# Why are these Python datetime conversions affected by local time (UTC offset and DST)?

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.10

I'm using Python 3.10.4 on Linux trying to convert naive [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) objects that represent UTC to a local time (UTC+1+DST).

What puzzles me is that converting a naive datetime to UTC seems to take the local timezone into consideration despite its `tzinfo` is `None` (as it should) - whereas going the other way, i.e. attempting to convert a datetime that is naive or aware (set to UTC) to the local [`timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects), does not seem to take DST into account.

That only works as expected when using [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) (new in 3.9) instead of `timezone`.

```
import datetime

print("naive as UTC")
# naive local time UTC+1 (DST +1) 
# -> UTC 22-07-07 06:02:34
naive = datetime.datetime(2022,7,7,8,2,34)
print( naive )
utc = naive.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
print(utc)


print("UTC as local")
utc = datetime.datetime(2022,7,7,8,2,34,tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
print( utc )

tz = datetime.timezone( datetime.timedelta(hours=1) )
local = naive.astimezone(tz)
print(local, local.dst() )

print("UTC as local with zoneinfo")
import zoneinfo
local = utc.astimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin"))
print(local, local.dst() )
```

Output

```
naive as UTC
2022-07-07 08:02:34
2022-07-07 06:02:34+00:00
UTC as local
2022-07-07 08:02:34+00:00
2022-07-07 07:02:34+01:00 None
UTC as local with zoneinfo
2022-07-07 10:02:34+02:00 1:00:00
```

On the other hand, the code for "UTC as local" does seem to handle DST but not the UTC offset:

```
UTC as local
2022-07-07 08:02:34+00:00
2022-07-07 07:02:34+01:00 None

UTC as local
2022-01-07 08:02:34+00:00
2022-01-07 08:02:34+01:00 None
```

While I get expected results using `zoneinfo`, I'd like to understand what is happening with the other "conversions" and why the system clock affects them (running the code on https://www.python.org/shell/ gives different results).

Comment: IIUC, you expect a timezone object that you derive from a timedelta to be aware of DST transitions?

Comment: Not really, but the first conversion "native to UTC" appears to be aware - why?

Comment: naive datetime is treated as local time, so it has to be aware of the current UTC offset, yes. Otherwise, you could not convert to UTC. It even has *some* DST awareness, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72804395/10197418

Comment: Then "naive datetime is treated as local time" should be documented explicitly. I agree with "could not convert" - converting a naive object should raise an Exception. One would have to make it aware with  `.replace(tzinfo=...)` first.

Comment: I agree, that's not very obvious from the docs. Python obtains local time (--> [time.localtime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime)) via your platform's C-libraries, see e.g. [time.h](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/). That's what also allows to determine the UTC offset, by comparison to time.gmtime.

Comment: [Actually](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone): "If self is naive, it is presumed to represent time in the system timezone."

Comment: `local = naive.astimezone(tz)` is an error, it should have been `utc`.

Comment: On the 7th of July your UTC offset is +2, so you need a timedelta of 2 hours to get to +0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a datetime object like this:

```
naive = datetime.datetime(2022,7,7,8,2,34)
```

You create a [naive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) object (that is not aware of the timezone). Following the documentation:

> Whether a naive object represents Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), local time, or
> time in some other timezone is purely up to the program, just like it
> is up to the program whether a particular number represents metres,
> miles, or mass.

I think you expect that this object will represent UTC time, but it's not true. It's simply unaware of the timezone so the timezone could be interpreted anyhow.

Let's look at source code of the astimezone method:

```
def astimezone(self, tz=None):

    ....

    mytz = self.tzinfo
    if mytz is None:
        mytz = self._local_timezone()
        myoffset = mytz.utcoffset(self)
    else:
       
    ....

    # Convert from UTC to tz's local time.
    return tz.fromutc(utc)
```

You see that when self.tzinfo is None then it interprets this as a local timezone rather than UTC

The other examples that you provided are aware of the timezone.

Comment: The interesting part starts with [`_local_timezone`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8bbd70b4d130f060f87e3f53810dc747a49fa369/Lib/datetime.py#L1956) - that's where Python starts to dig in to the platform's C library to determine the UTC offset. That's also why DST transitions *kind of* work in timedelta arithmetic, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72804650/10197418).

Comment: I expected it to be naive and probably meant to set it to UTC (incorrecly) using astimezone() -  since that conversion had intended results I somewhere got confused along the way.

Answer (score 0):

To make a *naive* `datetime` object *aware*, do not use [`.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone), as that assumes your system's local time for your naive object:

> If self is naive, it is presumed to represent time in the system timezone.

Use [`.replace(tzinfo=...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) instead.

Comment: ...unless somebody still uses pytz ;-) And if you *want* aware datetime in your local tz, then `.astimezone(None)` is kind of ok; although the tzinfo will not be a proper timezone object, just on that's derived from a timedelta (don't do timedelta arithmetic across DST transitions with that).